# How can I get a CSV file from a provided url and store it temporarily so I can processes it?

Tags: php, csv, curl

The user provides a location of a set of CSV files such as, `http://example.com/csvfiles/`. I then append the filenames to that url and "download" the files so I can process the data and store to a database. I want to use a temp file since the user can also upload files directly. I'm trying to run the same function for upload and automation. The function takes in a file so I'd much rather pass a temp file instead of rewrite my code to take in an array or other format.

`allow_url_fopen` isn't set to true and I have no way of doing that on the server so I'm attempting to use `cURL` to get the CSV data.

I've tried the following:

```
$path = sys_get_temp_dir();
$prodFile = tempnam($path, 'sfProd');
$prodTemp = fopen($prodFile,'w+');
$prodCurl = curl_init($fileLoc.'prod.csv');
curl_setopt($prodCurl, CURLOPT_FILE, $prodTemp);
curl_setopt($prodCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($prodCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_exec($prodCurl);
curl_close($prodCurl);
fclose($prodFile);

echo file_get_contents($prodFile,FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

but `fclose()` complains that `fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `fclose($prodTemp);` ?

Comment: You need to pass the file handler  $prodTemp to fclose. You also want to call fclose after you write to it.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: That fixed the error! Thanks! How can I validate `curl_setopt($prodCurl, CURLOPT_FILE, $prodTemp);` wrote to the file? `echo file_get_contents($prodFile);` returns empty...

Comment: nevermind I had a setting wrong. `file_get_contents` works